# Using my Python TCP Server to Communicate with my Android App

Tags: java, android, python, sockets, kotlin

I'm trying to make an app that is being monitored by my Python server; the server can send requests to the app, and then the app would send a message back to the server saying if the request was accepted or denied. I do have to use a Python server and I would like my app to be in Kotlin. For example, the app will inform the server that bluetooth is on, and the server would send a request to turn it off, then the app would send a message back telling the server if the user said yes or no to the request.

I have code for server and client using TCP sockets that I made last year. In this case, the client would be the Android app.

Here is a very small code sample to show where I'm going:

```py
#SERVER
import socket

HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 10000
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    print("main socket is listening...")
    connection, address = s.accept()
    with connection:
        print('Connected by', address,'\n')
        connection.sendall(b'Thank you for connecting!')

#CLIENT
import socket

HOST = ''  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 1000        # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))

    # print thank you message
    print(s.recv(1024).decode(encoding='utf-8'))
```

With that being said, would a be able to work with my Python TCP server, or should I go another direction that uses a Python back-end?

Comment: It doesnt matter what language is on the back-end, kotlin sockets will be able to connect to it.

Comment: @Dylan That's true, but there isn't much information available about using sockets with Kotlin.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/antonyalkmim/CalculatorKT

Comment: I have used both the libraries and it works great

https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket
https://github.com/gusavila92/java-android-websocket-client